Updating or adding migration script and automating the db creation or update
I have an existing project with migration scripts. I automated the db update using
-- code to update the database on Application start
Database.SetInitializer<DataContextInst>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatest<DataContextInst,MyProcess.DataContextInst.Inst>(true));

// Force the database update
using (var context=new DataContextInst(true))
    context.Database.Initialize(false);

This created the database tables
Now, I have updated the models with property annotation. I generated the migration scripts using Add-Migration -Config Inst and named them Inst_PropertyAnnotation. This created a new migration class.
However, when the application is started, the new changes don't get updated. When I checked the Inst_PropertyAnnotation.Ddesigner.cs the version history is the same for the initial migration class and the new one.

How to update the data annotation changes to already existing db
How to create the database table with the data annotation

I tried by creating the migration scripts with existign class name but it got created a new class. Not updated the old one.
I tried removing the older files and create a new one. Doesnt sound a good solution
